# Passing a 2d-array from Julia to Fortran

Tags: c, fortran, julia

I'm having trouble passing a 2d-array from Julia to Fortran.

Passing that 2d-array to a C function works fine though.

Here is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double meanFilter(int **arr, int row, int col)
{
    int i, j, sum=0;
    float mean;
    for (i=0; i<row; i=i+1)
        for (j=0; j<col; j=j+1) {
             sum = sum + arr[i][j];
             printf("%d %d %d %d\n", i, j, arr[i][j], sum);
         }
    mean = (double)sum / (row * col);
    printf("mean=%f\n", mean);
    return mean;
}
```

that i compile with

```
icc -o myclib.so myclib.c -fPIC -shared
```

and the Julia code where I call the C function:

```
x = zeros(Cint,5,5)
for i=1:5
    for j=1:5
        x[i,j] = i * j
        print(x[i,j], " ")
    end
    println()
end

refAr = [Ref(x,i) for i=1:size(x,1):length(x)]

aMean = ccall((:meanFilter, :myclib), Float64, (Ptr{Ptr{Cint}}, Cint, Cint), refAr, 5, 5)
println("mean_c=",aMean)
```

and I get this output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 4 6 8 10 
3 6 9 12 15 
4 8 12 16 20 
5 10 15 20 25 
0 0 1 1
0 1 2 3
0 2 3 6
0 3 4 10
0 4 5 15
1 0 2 17
1 1 4 21
1 2 6 27
1 3 8 35
1 4 10 45
2 0 3 48
2 1 6 54
2 2 9 63
2 3 12 75
2 4 15 90
3 0 4 94
3 1 8 102
3 2 12 114
3 3 16 130
3 4 20 150
4 0 5 155
4 1 10 165
4 2 15 180
4 3 20 200
4 4 25 225
mean=9.000000
mean_c=9.0
```

Here is the Fortran version:

```
real(kind=8) function meanFilter(arr, row, col)
    integer, intent(in) :: row, col
    integer, dimension(row,col), intent(in) :: arr
    integer :: i, j, sum

    sum = 0

    do j=1, col
        do i = 1, row
            sum = sum + arr(i,j)
            write(*,*) i, j, arr(i,j), sum
        enddo
    enddo
    meanFilter = real(sum,8)/(row*col)
    write(*,*) "mean=", meanFilter
end function meanFilter
```

that I compile like this:

```
ifort -o myflib.so myflib.f90 -assume byterecl -shared -fPIC
```

and the Julia code

```
x = zeros(Cint,5,5)
for i=1:5
    for j=1:5
        x[i,j] = i * j
        print(x[i,j], " ")
    end
    println()
end

refAr = [Ref(x,i) for i=1:size(x,1):length(x)]

aMean = ccall((:simplemodule_mp_meanfilter_, :myflib), Float64, (Ptr{Ptr{Cint}}, Cint, Cint), refAr, 5, 5)
println("mean_f=",aMean)
```

and I get this output:

```
signal (11): Segmentation fault
while loading ./fortran_call_in_julia.jl, in expression starting on line 56
simplemodule_mp_meanfilter_ at ./myflib.so (unknown line)
anonymous at ./<missing> (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ab08d75fcfa)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ab08d73b606)
jl_load at /usr/bin/../lib64/libjulia.so.0.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ab0991bd4e5)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ab0991bd6bb)
jl_apply_generic at /usr/bin/../lib64/libjulia.so.0.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ab0990625bf)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ab09906262b)
jl_apply_generic at /usr/bin/../lib64/libjulia.so.0.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ab0991c6315)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ab0991c87f4)
unknown function (ip: 0x2ab0991c9288)
jl_apply_generic at /usr/bin/../lib64/libjulia.so.0.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x401d90)
unknown function (ip: 0x401592)
__libc_start_main at /usr/bin/../lib64/libc.so.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x401649)
Allocations: 1664692 (Pool: 1663483; Big: 1209); GC: 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, what is it I'm doing wrong for the fortran version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortran uses call by reference even for simple integral arguments. Additionaly you are creating redundant layer of indirection here (in the both C and Fortran versions). So corrected julia wrapper for your fortran code should be:

```
x = zeros(Cint,5,5)
for i=1:5
    for j=1:5
        x[i,j] = i * j
        print(x[i,j], " ")
    end
    println()
end

aMean = ccall((:meanfilter_, "./tst.so"), Float64, (Ref{Cint}, Ref{Cint}, Ref{Cint}), x, 5, 5)
println("mean_f=",aMean)
```

---

I tested this with `gfortran` so your name mangling may differ.